# Array of strings function error, can't print the order correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, function, switch-statement

I have a problem with my code. I need to print the last default case in alphabetical order, but I'm not sure why it's not working. I have to take my stringArray, append two more strings to it and print out the correct case in my code. Apparently from what I was told I was printing against the original, unsorted list. But I'm not sure what I did wrong here.

Here is my code

```
var stringArray = ["zebra", "JAGUAR", "apple"]

func exFunction(par1: [String]) {

var parVar = par1
var secArray = [String]()

switch par1.count{

   //Reverses strings in the array
case 1...3:
    for j in par1 {
        let reverse = j.characters.reverse()
         secArray.append(String(reverse))
    }
    print(secArray)

    //Reverse the element order
case 4...6:
    for _ in 1...par1.count{

        secArray.append(parVar.popLast()!)
    }
    print(secArray)

   //Prints strings in alphabetical order
default:
    for i in par1 {
        secArray.append(i.lowercaseString)
    }
    secArray = secArray.sort()
    for p in par1 {
        print(p)
    }
}
}

exFunction(stringArray)

stringArray.append("Blue")
stringArray.append("eMerald")
exFunction(stringArray)

stringArray.append("beads")
stringArray.append("BEAR")
exFunction(stringArray)
```

The output should be:

["arbez", "RAUGAJ", "elppa"]

["eMerald", "Blue", "apple", "JAGUAR", "zebra"]

apple, 
beads,
BEAR,
Blue,
eMerald,
JAGUAR,
zebra

Comment: Could you add the expected output, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a typo:

```
default:
    for i in par1 {
        containerArray.append(i.lowercaseString)
    }
    containerArray = containerArray.sort()
    for p in containerArray { // instead of par1
        print(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg i knew it was something dumb. Thank you lol.

Comment: This looks ... familiar

Comment: Ok.... out of respect for you, I've edited it away. I didn't see your answer before editing it

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error. Array indices start at `0`, so the range of valid indices in a 6-element array is `0` to `5`, so your `case 4...6` is probably walking off the end of the array.

Comment: I don't think so. Indices start at 0, but an array with 6 elements in it has length 6, and `a...b` means a (inclusive) through b (exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you looping and printing the elements of `par1`, not your sorted `containerArray`.

What do you think of this?

```
//Original Strings
var stringArray = ["zebra", "JAGUAR", "apple"]

func thirdFunction(par1: [String]) { //par1 should have a better name
    var result: [String]

    switch par1.count {
    case 1...3: //Reverses strings in the array
        result = par1.map{ String($0.characters.reverse) }

    case 4...6: //Reverse the element order
        result = par1.reverse

    default:    //Prints strings in alphabetical order
        result = par1.map{ $0.lowercaseString }.sorted()
    }

    print(result)
}

print("//Switch 1-3 Strings")
thirdFunction(stringArray)

print("//Switch 4-6 Strings")
stringArray.append("Blue")
stringArray.append("eMerald")
thirdFunction(stringArray)

print("//Switch >6 Strings")
stringArray.append("beads")
stringArray.append("BEAR")
thirdFunction(stringArray)
```

## Output:

> //Switch 1-3 Strings
>
> ["arbez", "RAUGAJ", "elppa"]
>
> //Switch 4-6 Strings
>
> ["eMerald", "Blue", "apple", "JAGUAR", "zebra"]
>
> //Switch >6 Strings
>
> ["apple", "beads", "bear", "blue", "emerald", "jaguar", "zebra"]